# What is the best way to Lint Angular 2, 4, 5 template html files prior to AOT compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, lint, tslint

I have found this [gulp html angular validate](https://github.com/ewu02/gulp-html-angular-validate)

but I am not entirely sure if this is event for angular 2 +.  Also, I was looking for something that was more like a lint, while you are working, versus during  a build process because AOT already does this upon building.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon [HTMLHint NG2](https://github.com/nikolasleblanc/HTMLHint-ng2), an extension for [HTMLHint](https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint), but both seem to be dead since they aren't updated for almost a year.

Apart from that, I didn't find any alternative.